# How to reduce the auto increment number in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Currently the table structure is like this:

```
user_preference
---------------
id
user_id
pref_id
```

this table store all the user options, and id is auto -inc

the problems are:

1) is it necessary to keep an ID for every table ? It seems the common practice to keep a system generated id for every table

2) whenever the user update their perference, I will clear all related record for him and insert the update one, the auto-inc number will become very large later. How can I prevent that?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which database are you using?  You have both MySQL and SQL Server tagged.

Comment: Regular `int` can hold `2^32` or `4294967296` - there's going to be quite some time until you exceed that. If you are worried you will exceed some 4.2 billion numbers, you can easily use `bigint` which equals to `18446744073709551615` - quite sufficient number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can periodically reset the auto increment counter back to 1, to ensure that the id does not become arbitrarily large (and sparse) over the course of frequent deletion of records.

**In MySQL:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

**In SQL Server:**

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED, 0)
```

Each of these commands will reset the auto increment counter to 1, or to the value closest to 1 if 1 be already in use by another record.

Comment: or is the id necessary? if reset the id will overlap

Comment: Danger Will Robinson: Make sure you have cascade properties set properly on any tables containing foreign keys referencing the primary key you are resetting.

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* need to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` for every table.  Sometimes there is a 'natural' key that works quite well for the PK.

Do not manipulate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.  Do not depend on any property other than uniqueness.

Your `user_preference` table smells like a many-to-many mapping?  If so, this is optimal:

```
CREATE TABLE user_preference (
    user_id ...,
    pref_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, pref_id),
    INDEX      (pref_id, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

For discussion of "why", see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table